# How to stop a for loop using Hotkey in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here's the piece of code that I've been testing out to check if I can stop a for loop using setTimeout and clearTimeout. The for loop keeps runs on and on.

```
var ticket, key;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
      if (e.key == "m") ticket = setTimeout(runMe,0); 
      if (e.key == "a") {clearTimeout(ticket); key = "a";}
})

function runMe(){
for (var i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
if (key == "a") break;   // doesn't work
myFunct(i); 
}
}

function myFunct(i){
console.log(i);
}
```

---

```
var ticket, key, i=0;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
      if (e.key == "m") ticket = setInterval(runMe,0,i++); 
      if (e.key == "a") {clearInterval(ticket); key = "a";}
})

function runMe(i){
console.log(i);
//myFunct(i); 

}

function myFunct(i){
console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: You can't. Javascript is single-threaded. Asynchronous code doesn't run until you return from the Javascript to the main event loop.

Comment: Is there an alternate way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run code repeatedly, and the `keydown` handler can use `clearInterval()` to stop it.

Comment: Apparently, thats the only thing that struck me as well after countless hours.  Didn't check it though, but still I initialize a counter inside the setTimeout function and clear the counter using clearTimeout, where the counter is used as an iterator for for loop, right ?

Comment: You don't use `setTimeout` **and** a `for` loop. `setTimeout` is **instead** of the loop.

Comment: Counter doesn't update despite having made the variable global !

Comment: You have to increment the counter in the function. You're just incrementing it one time when you start the timer.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to do it correctly, why do you keep changing the question?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop synchronous code with asynchronous code, because the async code isn't executed until you return to the main event loop.

If you want to run something repeatedly, use `setInterval`, then clear it when the event occurs.

```js
var counter = 0;
var interval;

function runMe() {
  if (counter == 1000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    counter++;
    $("#output").text(counter);
  }
}

$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'm') {
    interval = setInterval(runMe, 10);
  } else if (e.key == 'a') {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a webworker to run the for loop code, then use [terminate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate) to halt the loop.

```
// forloop.js
for (var i=0; i < 1000000; i++){
  myFunct(i); 
}

function myFunct(i){
  console.log(i);
}

// index.js
var myWorker;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.key == "m") myWorker = new Worker('forloop.js'); 
  if (e.key == "a") {myWorker.terminate();}
})
```

Note: code is not tested, only to give you the rough idea

Comment: Brilliant idea, will surely check it out

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded, so your key handler will not run until after the `runMe()` function has run till completion.

You can instead build an asynchronous looping function using `setTimeout()` (or `setInterval()`), so that other code - like a key handler - gets a chance to run in between iterations of the "loop".

I'd suggest encapsulating the loop-handling code inside the `runMe()` function and have `runMe()` return a function that can be called to stop the current loop. That way you can easily have multiple, unrelated loops going at the same time and stop them independently - you'd need to keep track of each, and I have not shown that in the code below, but it's not much more than what I have shown. (If you make the loop counter a single global variable then obviously you can't have separate concurrent loops.)

```js
var stopLoop;

$(document).on("keydown", function(e){
  if (e.key == "m") stopLoop = runMe(); 
  if (e.key == "a") stopLoop();
});

function runMe(){
  var i=0;
  var last=300; // I've used a smaller number so that you don't have to
                // wait too long to see see that it stops by itself if
                // you don't press "a" in the meantime
  var stop = false;
  
  (function looper() {
    myFunct(i);
    if (++i < last && !stop)
      setTimeout(looper, 5);
  })();
  
  return function() { stop = true; }
}
  
function myFunct(i){
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```